# Connecting JSON to a Datatable

Tags: jquery, json, datatable, datatables

I am using DataTable and have a source which returns JSON and this data is stored in a variable 'myJson' which has first name, last name and contact type in the following format:

```
var myJson = "[ 
       {
           "fname" : "Smith",
          "lname" : "Hardy",
         "contactType" : "Permanent"
      }, {
        "fname" : "Justin",
        "lname" : "Joshua",
        "contactType" : "Permanent"
    }, {
        "fname" : "Linda",
        "lname" : "Gary",
        "contactType" : "Temporary"
    }, {
        "fname" : "Dan",
        "lname" : "Kevin",
        "contactType" : "Temporary"
    }, {
        "fname" : "Linda",
        "lname" : "Jenman",
        "contactType" : "Temporary"
    }, {
        "fname" : "Willams",
        "lname" : "Steve",
        "contactType" : "Temporary"
    }, {
        "fname" : "Dan",
        "lname" : "Kevin",
        "contactType" : "Temporary"
    }, {
        "fname" : "Robert",
        "lname" : "Ryan",
        "contactType" : "Temporary"
    }, {
        "fname" : "Richard",
        "lname" : "Kevin",
        "contactType" : "Temporary"
    }, {
        "fname" : "Evon",
        "lname" : "Godwin",
        "contactType" : "Permanent"
    }, {
        "fname" : "Charles",
        "lname" : "Ben",
        "contactType" : "Temporary"
    }
]"
```

Here is my JavaScript code to connect to JSON and display data in the DataTable.

```js
      $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#tblEmployees').DataTable( {
          //how to connect to JSON to display data in DdataTable
       } );
   } );
```

Below is my Table HTML markup to display the information:

```
<table id="tblEmployees" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>First Name</th>
       <th>Last Name</th>
       <th>Contact Type</th>
   </tr>
</thead>            
</table>
```

What is the best way to connect JSON to my DataTable?

Comment: dataTables have tons and tons of examples, like this -> **https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html**, after checking the code out, scroll down to the bottom of the page and see lots of other examples. If you dont want to load from a file, use `data: myJson, dataSrc: ''`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = [];
    data.push(
        [1,"Sasha","Brenna","0800 1111"],
        [2,"Sage","Mia","(01012) 405872"],
        [3,"Chelsea","Allistair","076 0578 0265"],
        [4,"Uta","Savannah","070 1247 5884"],
        [5,"Remedios","Berk","0995 181 0007"],
        [6,"Ruby","Wayne","0800 1111"],
        [7,"Faith","Fredericka","(01709) 099879"],
        [8,"Myra","Harrison","070 4241 9576"],
        [9,"Drake","Miriam","0800 733635"],
        [10,"Reed","Shannon","076 8597 5067"]
    );

    $('#data_table').DataTable( {
        data: data
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aej470qm/)